# Implicit differentiation of an exponential with a function within a function

Tags: derivatives

$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(y+1)^{x+1}$

I was wondering how to solve the question above, or approach this question.

I tried it this way, it was  wrong.

The first way I made $y=(y+1)^{x+1}$  (1) and then took the natural log on both sides differentiated, and then subbed (1) in, but it was not correct. So I was wondering why a) am I wrong b) how to solve this

Thank you!

Comment: You have to have an equation for implicit differentiation.

Comment: How do i do that @ParasKhosla

Comment: What was the question that you were trying to solve?

Comment: @ParasKhosla it says it at the top, I will make it more clear one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}y&=(y+1)^{x+1}\\ \ln y&=(x+1)\ln (y+1)\\ \frac{y'}{y}&=\ln(y+1)+\frac{x+1}{y+1}\cdot y'\\ y'\left[\frac{1}{y}-\frac{x+1}{y+1}\right]&=\ln(y+1)\\ y'&=\ln(y+1)\cdot \left[\dfrac{y(y+1)}{y-x}\right]\end{aligned}$$

Now all you have to do is solve for $y'$. Can you proceed?

Comment: I did this but I got the answer wrong! The answer is $y(lny)^2/(1-xlny)$

Comment: Try plotting the solution you got. Maybe they would be equivalent expressions or the solution in the book might be wrong. This logic I believe is correct.

Comment: Okay I will, I also wanted to add that for the fourth line shouldn't it be y'[1/y - .....] instead of y?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit it. Thanks